# Set one corner radius for every element of form

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to do simple rounded corners stuck in a problem - usually there are a style for every element, but I just dlike to make rounded borders with the same round corners for all my controls in grid - there are mostly textBoxes and buttons. I could set BorderBrush for every control - is it possible to set border radius?

I have add :

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And this have not affected no buttons :

```
<Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="Transparent" >Change Location</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `App.xaml`, you could define a global style for a `Border`, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
</Style>
```

This will affect **all** `Borders`, unless a `Style` explicitly sets this value.

Comment: Sorry, but this will no effect for me - please take a look at updated question